# selected value to any item selected in combobox give me null why

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

**Problem**

**Selected value to any item in combo box  give me null why**

**Details**

I work in windows form c# visual studio 2015

And i get data of combo box from excel sheet 2007

excel sheet have two column

MemberId represent value to combo box

MemberName represent text to combo box

```
 var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\Book3105", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var connection = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source={0};Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;", fileName);

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + "D:\\Book3105.xlsx" + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\"");
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            str = "select * from [sheet2$]";
            com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
            oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
            ds = new DataSet();
            oledbda.Fill(ds, "[sheet2$]");
            con.Close();

            dt = ds.Tables["[sheet2$]"];
            int i = 0;


            for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                comboBox4.Items.Insert(0, "select member");
                comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;
                comboBox4.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

When debug this line under button give me null

and message box show to me when select any item in combo box .

```
private void buttontest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           if(Convert.ToInt32(comboBox4.SelectedValue)==0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong value");

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` for your combobox after you populate the combobox.Ensure the property of the combobox is set to `DropDownStyle: DropDownList`

```
for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
     comboBox4.Items.Insert(0, "select member");
     comboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0;
     comboBox4.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1]);
}

comboBox4.ValueMember = "MemberId";
comboBox4.DisplayMember = "MemberName";
```

Then in the button_click event check the SelectedItem value like

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(((KeyValuePair<string,string >)comboBox4.SelectedItem).Key) == 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("wrong value");
}
```